# App.Config bundling

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, appsettings

Is there a way to have 'bundled' application configuration files similar to the web.config-Transformations?

```
/// app.config

  <bla>value</bla>
  <connectionStrings configSource="Config/connections.config />

/// connections.config
  <connectionString>
     <clear />
```

which would result into

```
/// MyApp.Config
  <bla>value</bla>
  <connectionString>
     <clear />
  </connectionString>
```

Currently, I have to mark all my configuration files as "Always copy"...

Answer (score 1):

There is a free plugin at
[Configuration Transform.](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859)